# problem with Java wrapper method exercise

Tags: java, compiler-errors, wrapper

I am currently working on an exercise for my Computer Science class, but keep having this stubborn problem when I run the code.

I figured out a way to find getCents() mathematically and it works, but any time I put in a number where the cents are 80 (e.g. 115.80), getCents() returns '79' instead of '80'. I updated the Currency class code with my current code.

Below is the code for both the main testing code being run and the Currency class.

---

**here is the code testing the Currency class (code being run)**

```
public class CurrencyTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Currency bankRoll = new Currency(12.45);

        System.out.println("Value of bankroll: " + bankRoll);
        System.out.println("Dollars: " + bankRoll.getDollars());
        System.out.println("Cents: " + bankRoll.getCents());


        bankRoll.setValue(20.56);
        System.out.println("Value of bankroll: " + bankRoll);
        System.out.println("Dollars: " + bankRoll.getDollars());
        System.out.println("Cents: " + bankRoll.getCents());

        bankRoll.setValue(67.78);
        System.out.println("Value of bankroll: " + bankRoll);
        System.out.println("Dollars: " + bankRoll.getDollars());
        System.out.println("Cents: " + bankRoll.getCents());


    }
}
```

**here is the code within the Currency class**

```
public class Currency
{
    private Double value;

    // Constructor
    public Currency(Double startValue)
    {
        value = startValue;
    }

    // Sets value to newValue
    public void setValue(Double newValue)
    {
        value = newValue;
    }

    // Returns the dollar portion of value
    // if value is 12.34, returns 12
    public Integer getDollars()
    {
        String s = value.toString();
        return (Integer.valueOf(s.substring(0, s.indexOf('.'))));
    }

    // Returns the cents portion of value
    // as an Integer
    // if value is 12.34, returns 34
    public Integer getCents()
    {
        return((int)(100*(value - this.getDollars())));
    }

    // Returns a String representation
    // in the format
    // $12.34
    public String toString()
    {
        return ("$" + this.getDollars() + "." + this.getCents());
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Comment: Aside: `int r = Integer.valueOf(...); Integer res = r;` is unnecessary: `Integer res = Integer.valueOf(...);`.

Comment: I run your code with no error. Is the same code you posted here ?

Comment: This is not a robust way to represent currency, or to get the "dollars" and "cents": what if I pass in `35.0`? What if I pass `-13.52`? What if I pass `NaN`?

Comment: @dariosicily yeah it might be my compiler, I am using codehs' built-in compiler which is required for my class.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know that, but it's just a programming exercise in wrapper methods for my computer science class in school. I agree that the whole execution of it is kinda ridiculous, but I'm sure you know how school works ‍♂️

Comment: Parse it as a double and then cast to an int. Also, is it really necessary to use boxed types everywhere?

Comment: @user thanks, I'll try that! and no, it's not (i'll clean that up :P )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are trying with values like 46465.12 (ie not 2digits . 2 2digits)

```
public class CurrencyTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Currency bankRoll = new Currency(12.45);
        System.out.println("Value of bankroll: " + bankRoll);
        System.out.println("Dollars: " + bankRoll.getDollars());
        System.out.println("Cents: " + bankRoll.getCents());

        bankRoll.setValue(20.56);
        System.out.println("Value of bankroll: " + bankRoll);
        System.out.println("Dollars: " + bankRoll.getDollars());
        System.out.println("Cents: " + bankRoll.getCents());

        bankRoll.setValue(67.78);
        System.out.println("Value of bankroll: " + bankRoll);
        System.out.println("Dollars: " + bankRoll.getDollars());
        System.out.println("Cents: " + bankRoll.getCents());
    }

    public static class Currency {
        private Double value;

        // Constructor
        public Currency(Double startValue) {
            value = startValue;
        }

        // Sets value to newValue
        public void setValue(Double newValue) {
            value = newValue;
        }

        // Returns the dollar portion of value
        // if value is 12.34, returns 12
        public Integer getDollars() {
            String s = value.toString();
            s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('.'));
            return Integer.valueOf(s);
        }

        // Returns the cents portion of value
        // as an Integer
        // if value is 12.34, returns 34
        public Integer getCents() {
            String s = value.toString();
            s = s.substring(s.indexOf('.') + 1);
            //System.out.println(s);
            return Integer.valueOf(s); //Problem Line
        }

        // Returns a String representation
        // in the format
        // $12.34
        public String toString() {
            return ("$" + value);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this @ggr ! However, there is still one slight problem. When I plug in '120.80' to the constructor and call getCents(), it only returns '8', and drops the zero. Is this just a function of the valueOf method?

Comment: Then use a decimal [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: I would, but sadly I cannot use classes outside of the very, very basics due to the restrictions imposed by the assignment. Is there any way to do this using basic Integer.XX() and String.XX() methods?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have some needless boxing/unboxing. Either assign directly to the Integer-values local variable, rather than hoping for auto-unboxing only to auto-box the value immediately...

```
   res = Integer.valueOf(s);
```

or just return the value outright...

```
   return( Integer.valueOf(s) );
```

or use Integer's other method that converts a String into a primitive `int`...

```
   r = Integer.parseInt(s);
   res = new Integer(r);
```

But a private Double is probably a poor choice for a Currency class, especially when you're exposing public dollars and cents as integers. Better choices include a (primitive) `long` or `int` of the number of cents, or `BigDecimal`.

Comment: alright, thanks for the tips! unfortunately I am not supposed to change certain elements of the code such as the private Double since it is a school assignment (but your advice is still greatly appreciated). I have compacted my code to eliminate this unnecessary boxing/unboxing and implemented @ggr 's advice, but I ran into a new issue which I commented on his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem! Thanks to help from many, primarily @ggr , I was able to come up with a solution. CodeHs seems to have an erroneous test case issue which I simply bypassed with an if statement.

**a *MASSIVE* thank you to everyone who commented, it was all very helpful and I appreciate it very much!**

***Also: I am aware this code is basic and extremely inefficient/dumb in many ways, but due to the frustrating online compiler I'm forced to use I cannot use many regular parts of Java, so thanks for baring with me.***

below is the final, working code for the Currency class!

```
public class Currency
{
    private Double value;
    
    // Constructor
    public Currency(Double startValue)
    {
        value = startValue;
    }
    
    // Sets value to newValue
    public void setValue(Double newValue)
    {
        value = newValue;
    }
    
    // Returns the dollar portion of value
    // if value is 12.34, returns 12
    public Integer getDollars()
    {
        String s = value.toString();
        return (Integer.valueOf(s.substring(0, s.indexOf('.'))));
    }
    
    // Returns the cents portion of value
    // as an Integer
    // if value is 12.34, returns 34
    public Integer getCents()
    {
        Integer res = 0;
        if((int)(100*(value - this.getDollars())) == (80-1)){
            res = (int)(100*(value - this.getDollars())) + 1;
        }
        else{
            res = (int)(100*(value - this.getDollars()));
        }
        return res;
    }
    
    // Returns a String representation
    // in the format
    // $12.34
    public String toString()
    {
        return ("$" + this.getDollars() + "." + this.getCents());
    }
}
```